# How to insert records in the database in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-activity

My `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.iq_test);

    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

    // Inserting Questions
    db.addQuestion(new Question("1. Question1", 1));
    db.addQuestion(new Question("2. Question2", 2));

    // Inserting Answers
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("2", 1, 0));
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("3", 1, 0));
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("4", 1, 1));
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("5", 1, 0));

    // Reading all Questions
    List<Question> questions = db.getAllQuestions();
    // Reading all Answers
    List<Answer> answers = db.getAllAnswers();

    // other code
}
```

I've created a new java file and i moved some of the code there. My new activity looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseContent extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.iq_test);

    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

    // Inserting Questions
    db.addQuestion(new Question("1. Question1", 1));
    db.addQuestion(new Question("2. Question2", 2));

    // Inserting Answers
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("2", 1, 0));
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("3", 1, 0));
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("4", 1, 1));
    db.addAnswer(new Answer("5", 1, 0));
}
```

The ramaining code from the `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.iq_test);

    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

    // Reading all Questions
    List<Question> questions = db.getAllQuestions();
    // Reading all Answers
    List<Answer> answers = db.getAllAnswers();

    // other code
}
```

I want to insert records in database from the `DatabaseContent` activity and in `MainActivity` i want only to read them. I know that in java it's not like in php to `include` files, but kind of. With this code, the records are not inserted in the database.
Also, when the `MainActivity` is recreated, i want the data not to be inserted again. How can i do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your DatabaseHelper Class while overriding onCreate Method

```
   DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(//Create your table first);
      --this will insert the master data when the table will be created for the first time 
   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + " (" + COL1 + ", " + COL2 + "," + COL3 + "," + COL4 + "," + COL5 + ","+COL6+")" +
            " VALUES(VAL1,VAL2,VAL3,VAL4,VAL5,VAL6);");
    }

  @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, i already have this. I just want the `db.addQuestion` and the `db.addAnswer` to be added from another activity. In this case, `DatabaseContent ` activity, rather than `MainActivity`.

Comment: Sorry but i can't edit my post yet. This is [my DBHandler](http://www.gogo.ro/29.txt)

Comment: Please also show code for addQuestion and addAnswer

Comment: Please refresh the page! You will find there the entire [DBHandler](http://www.gogo.ro/29.txt)

Comment: your addQuestion and addAnswer code seems to be fine.. wat is the exception coming.. can you check with loggers

Comment: What does it mean 'check with loggers'? When i turn on the emulator, i get no errors and when the application starts, no question and no answer are displayed. This means that no record was inserted. Am i wrong?

Comment: you are right!!! Reinstall your application  long id = db.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, values);  check value of id

Comment: Do you have any idea what can be done, to insert those records into the database?

Comment: If i use `long id = db.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, values);` in stead of `db.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, values);` also nothing happens :|

Comment: I don't where to place `long id = db.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, values);` and where to read that `-1`. Can you please give me an example or edit that text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94968/discussion-between-zero-and-alex-m).

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your insert and fetch queries but I recommend you follow the correct programming practice of inserting data using Models and implementing the Base Columns class which gives you handy utilities like _ID , Count and other stuff. You can use this tutorial as a [walk through](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea of how can i solve this issue? This is my [DBHandler](http://www.gogo.ro/29.txt)